# bootstrap 4 responsive card grid/ array

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm trying to do something similar to codepen's [dashboard](https://codepen.io/dashboard), or if you don't have an account you can just check codepen's [home screen](https://codepen.io).

I have a dynamic list of cards but I want it to be responsive and the number of cards in row to decrease with respect to the viewport size.

I thought bootstrap could help it, but all i have tried didnt work. Note that the number of cards can vary dynamically

here is a [pen](https://codepen.io/xsmael/pen/qgppbE) of what I got so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 " style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="card card-default" >

            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h3>Card</h3>
            <h6>Today</h6>
            <p><strong>5 Errors</strong></p>
            <p><strong>3 Warnings</strong></p>
            <p><strong>1 Info</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 " style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="card edge-danger card-warning" >
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h3>Card</h3>
            <h6>Today</h6>
            <p><strong>5 Errors</strong></p>
            <p><strong>3 Warnings</strong></p>
            <p><strong>1 Info</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 " style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="card edge-danger card-default" >
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h3>Card</h3>
            <h6>Today</h6>
            <p><strong>5 Errors</strong></p>
            <p><strong>3 Warnings</strong></p>
            <p><strong>1 Info</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 " style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="card edge-danger card-danger" >
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h3>Card</h3>
            <h6>Today</h6>
            <p><strong>5 Errors</strong></p>
            <p><strong>3 Warnings</strong></p>
            <p><strong>1 Info</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 " style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="card edge-danger card-white" >
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h3>Card</h3>
            <h6>Today</h6>
            <p><strong>5 Errors</strong></p>
            <p><strong>3 Warnings</strong></p>
            <p><strong>1 Info</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 " style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="card edge-danger card-danger" >
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h3>Card</h3>
            <h6>Today</h6>
            <p><strong>5 Errors</strong></p>
            <p><strong>3 Warnings</strong></p>
            <p><strong>1 Info</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 " style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="card edge-danger card-white" >
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h3>Card</h3>
            <h6>Today</h6>
            <p><strong>5 Errors</strong></p>
            <p><strong>3 Warnings</strong></p>
            <p><strong>1 Info</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it results in this.
[image]

but when I reduce the widow width the ratio is lost i want it to rather go to the next row and so on.... while using the full width space available.
[image]

What am trying to do is this:
[image]

scaling down...
[image]

scaling down further...
[image]

Comment: if you want you grid columns to change size at certain breakpoints you can provide the appropriate classes. i.e (this `col-md-2` could become this `col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6`

Comment: @zgood okay but how  to  keep the height/ width ratio ?

Comment: Well there is nothing in your post about maintaining aspect ratios.... thats kind of a whole different question. You can check out this [css aspect ratio trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) that uses `padding-top` to maintain the ratio.

Comment: @zgood there i mentioned it and added the second pictuer to show that issue too, thanks for the link am gonna check it.

Answer (score 3):

Use Bootstrap's responsive breakpoints. For example:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-6" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
      <div class="card card-default">
          ...
      </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/WfAaguTKos

Comment: thanks,  but how to prevent the cards from losing height/ width ratio ? when the screen gets smaller

Answer (score 2):

You can use many 'col' classes, one for each size of the window

```
class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"
```

On this example the cards will be on this way:
6 on large screens, 4 on mediun screens, 3 on small and 2 on very small screens.